# Ember does not update value of <input text> based on another property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi i have a simple code that updates a component's property value e.g. with a button click, and based on that value i need to update the `value` of the input text, like so:

template:
`{{input value=myValue type="text" }}
<button {{action "update"}}>update</button>`

component.js:
`myValue: Ember.computed("product", function(){
    if(this.get("product")) {
      return this.get("product");
    }
  }),
 actions:
   update(){ this.set('product', 'new value')}`

But although, the "product" property is updated , the input value stays the same,
`computed` function is not triggered.

### `<input>` after button click, should be:

[image]

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

`{{input}}` template helper does a two-way binding. For good reasons this is considered a bad practice these days. You face one of this issues.

If input value changes `{{input}}` template helper sets the new value on `myValue`. This overrides your computed property cause that one does not implement a setter. Afterwards your input is not bound to `product` anymore. Therefor changing `product` will not update the input.

You have different ways to address this issue. One option would be to implement a setter in `myValue` computed property or simply use a macro like `computed.alias`.  But I would recommend to drop the input helper and it's two-way binding. Instead set the value explicitly on change: `<input value={{myValue}} onchange={{mut "product" value="target.value"}}>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to only update a value on the button press, I suggest using an action on the button.

template.hbs

```
<button {{action "updateProduct" product}}>update</button>
```

component.js

```
actions: {
    updateProduct(product) {
        this.set('product', product);
    }
}
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you here.

Answer (score 0):

So, 
 what i need here is a 2-way data bind, because i update `myValue` from :
1. input text
2. from 'product'

My computed method needs slightly refactor, to add a `getter` & `setter`, like so:

`myValue: Ember.computed("product", function(){
    get(key){
      return this.get("product");
    },
    set(key, value){
      this.set(product', value);
      return value;
  }),`